# For a Ruby CLI, what is the most reliable way to change directory to users root/home directory?

Tags: ruby, command-line-interface

Really I'm not sure whether to ask the user to make sure they are in their home directory before running the commands and abort if not or just change the directory for them?

`Dir.chdir` without an argument defaults to the users home directory, and when the block finishes it returns to the previous directory

```
Dir.chdir do 
  puts Dir.pwd
end

puts Dir.pwd

# => 'Users/Brian'

# => '/Users/Brian/gems/etc...'
```

I would need to `chdir` quite a few times throughout the code. Is this pretty reliable?

Anybody have any insight on the best way to do this kind of thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize [Avdi Grimm's screencast on the same subject](http://www.rubytapas.com/episodes/10-Finding-HOME),

If you're using a Ruby version greater than 1.9, the `Dir` module provides a method `#home`. However, this depends on the environment variable `HOME` set on the user's shell session. To reliably get the home dir, you should pass in the login name of the current user to the `Dir.home` command. Or, in code:

```
# Works if HOME is set in the environment i.e., if "echo $HOME" returns the home directory
# when that command is run on the command-line
Dir.home     # => /Users/<username>, Works if HOME is set

# If the HOME environment variable is not set, you should explicitly pass in the username
# of the currently logged-in user
Dir.home(username)     # => /Users/<username>

# The current username can be obtained using
username = `whoami`

# or

require 'etc'
username = Etc.getlogin
```

Now for the final caveat: This works on *nix.